# content_scripts of Chrome manifes.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

my file manifes.js look like this

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Youtube test",
  "description": "This extension lalala",
  "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
    "128" : "icon.png"
  },
   "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://youtube.com/*"],
        "js": ["test.js"]
      }
    ]
}
```

my test.js try to console to test it work or not

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
window.onload=function(){console.log('work test');};
</script>
```

but it does nothing when I go to youtube? What's wrong?

Comment: Remove the `<script>` tags.. What makes you think that they are necessary? If you open the JavaScript console, you'd see that your code triggers a syntax error.

Comment: @RobW forgot to mention, I tried that earlier.. that's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: You have to remove `window.onload = function(){` and `};` at the end as well. By default a content script runs at `document_idle`, when `window.onload` has already run.

Comment: so just console.log('test') on test.js? I did that still doesn't work..

Comment: Don't forget to reload the extension at `chrome://extensions/` and refresh the tab.

Comment: thx @RobW. It work, it's because youtube.com has the www thing and I missed that! thx!